# Regarding paypal REST API

Tags: rest, paypal

I am experienced with REST API development, but a newb to paypal's apis. A client asked me to add payments to a web game I am working on for him, the transaction will be done on a webpage, and my plan is to have a script put the item in a DB for later use.

Which Paypal API would I want to use for in game credits? there is just so many on their screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting started with the basic client-side integration:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/